# Setting width in C# ActiveForm has no effect

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I need to access the size of the form, so I declare a `int` variables height and width.
The code looks like this:

```
int width = Form1.ActiveForm.Width;
```

and the same for height.

I set the width to 800 but every time it returns 300.
What's the problem?

Comment: Please show us the code in which you "set the width".

Comment: Is `Form1` the form you are running this code from?

Comment: Just to clear, is this what you're doing: `Form1.ActiveForm.Width = 800;` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you've said, and assuming that the code is running from Form1:

```
int width = this.Width;
int height = this.Height;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your [maximum width](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.maximumsize.aspx) is 300 so you cannot set the width to a higher value.

Comment: Deutscher? ^_^ If you remove the `de-de/` then everyone who clicks the link will get the page translated according to his own language settings.

Comment: Vielen Dank für die Info!

Comment: This automated translation is one of the most horrible misfeatures ever. Who the hell wants to read a machine-translated article instead of an english one anyway - especially in IT?

Comment: Well, I think at least the german translation is pretty good. And yes, even in IT there are a lot of people less than fluent in english. The point is to give everyone the choice instead of hard-coding it to en-US. If you want the original, you can have it with one more click or even change your setting to always display that.